# Ĉu estas paĝo por kongresoj kaj aliaj eventoj?

Tags: culture, websites

Ĉu ie troviĝas kunigita kalendaro de ĉiuj internaciaj esperanto-renkontiĝoj? La plejmulto pri ĉi tiaj aferoj mi ricevis babilante. Estus bone havi oficialan skribitan informon. Ĉu eble estas listo de  ĉiu-jare revenantaj renkontiĝoj?

Answer (score 4):

Mi nur scias pri [ĉi tiu paĝo](http://eventoj.hu/2016.htm). Ĝi enhavas kalendaron por la eventoj ĉirkaŭ la mondo en 2016 kaj 2017.

Answer (score 1):

Estas bona ideo. Mi nur scias pri ĉi tiu: http://lernu.net/en/forumo/2